# Display dynamically generated SVG in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I'm dynamically generating a pie chart into an SVG. Which works fine in most browsers but it doesn't seem that IE 8 supports it. I've heard of falling back to a .png but that isn't an option, since the svg is dynamically generated.

Is it possible to render what the SVG would have produced in IE 8?

Comment: IE8 does not support SVG natively. Some plugins such as the adobe SVG plugin can provide SVG support though.

Comment: I understand that IE8 doesn't support SVG natively. I was looking for a work around. Like converting the SVG into a png on the fly